# How many times to differentiate to obtain differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following question:

[image]

Find the differential equation of the family of curves, $x^2=4b(y+b)$ ($b$ is a real arbitrary constant).

Now, if we differentiate the given equation twice, we get $xy''=y'$. However, if we only differentiate once, we get $x(y')^2=x+2yy'$

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always remember:** *A differential equation of the $n^\text{th}$ order cannot have more than $n$ arbitrary constants in its solution*.

Here in your question, the solution curve of the differential equation $~x^2=4b(y+b)~$ contains only one arbitrary constant $b$ and hence the *order of the differential equation is exactly **one***. So you need not differentiate the function for more than one time.

Now given curve is $$x^2=4b(y+b)\implies y+b=\dfrac{x^2}{4b}\tag1$$
Differentiate with respect to $x$ we have $~y'=\dfrac{x}{2b}\implies b=\dfrac{x}{2y'}~$

Putting the value of $b$ in $(1)$ we have the required differential equation as, $$x^2=2\dfrac{x}{y'}\left(y+\dfrac{x}{2y'}\right)\implies x\left(y'\right)^2=x+2yy'\implies x\left(y'\right)^2-2yy'=x~.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\require{cancel}$
Assuming $y=y(x)$ and $y'=\dfrac{d y}{dx}$

$$f(y,x):=\;\;\;x^2=4b(y+b)$$

\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{df(y,x)}{dx}\hspace{1cm}\Rightarrow\hspace{1cm}\dfrac{d}{dx}x^2=\dfrac{d}{dx}4b(y+b)=\dfrac{d}{dx}(4by+4b^2)\\
&\dfrac{df(y,x)}{dx}\hspace{1cm}\Rightarrow\hspace{1cm}2x=4by'+0\\
&\dfrac{d^2f(y,x)}{dx^2}\hspace{1cm}\Rightarrow\hspace{1cm}2=4by''
\end{align*}

The given family of curves seems to be wrong as the ODE we get is drastically different from the given ones.

Let's see if at least the two given ODE are related to each other:

$$g(y,x):=\;\;\;x(y')^2=x+2yy'$$

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{d\;g(y,x)}{dx}\hspace{1cm}\Rightarrow\hspace{1cm}1\cdot(y')^2+x\cdot2y'\cdot y''&=1+2(y'\cdot y'+ y\cdot y'')\\
\cancel{y'y'}+2xy'y''&=1+\cancel{2}y'y'+2yy''\\
xy''&=\dfrac{1+y'y'+2yy''}{2y'}=\dfrac{1}{2y'}+\dfrac{y'}{2}+\dfrac{yy''}{y'}\color{red}{\neq}xy''=y'
\end{align*}

This one is wrong too. What could have the author mean?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the linear family of a Clairaut equation. Identifying the parts you get $\frac{d(x^2)}{dy}=4b\iff x\frac{dx}{dy}=2b$. Now insert back to get
$$
x^2=2xy\frac{dx}{dy}+x^2\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2
$$
Now revert back the functional dependency
$$
xy'^2=2yy'+x.
$$